# Custom Print block on Magento

Tags: magento, printing

I am using Magento 1.9. How can I allow Show Description block on print function? I can edit only the CSS file...

I couldn't find any solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a minimal, reproducible example. Please check this guide and consider adding an example to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're right. But the problem is that I don't have any clue where is any Print Blocks or something on Magento.